# Python OOP: How do I link multiple classes objects to one object

Tags: python, class, oop

For example:

```
class Person(object):
    name = ""
    age  = ""

class Address(object):
    title  = ""
    street = ""
    city   = ""
    state  = ""
    zip    = ""
```

Let's assume I have created two Person objects.

```
sally = Person()
sally.name = "Sally"
sally.age  = 22

john  = Person()
john.name = "John"
john.age  = 20
```

If each person had only one address I could easily just put it as an attribute to the person object. However, these people have both a work address and a home address.

```
sally_work = Address()
sally_work.title  = "Work"
sally_work.street = "123 Random Ave"
etc..

sally_home = Address()
sally_home.title  = "Home"
sally_home.street = "456 Foo St"
etc..

john_work = Address()
john_work.title  = "Work"
john_work.street = "7899 Work Ave"
etc..

john_home = Address()
john_home.title  = "Home"
john_home.street = "541 Character Ave"
etc..
```

Right now these addresses are not connected in any way to their corresponding person objects. In Django I would put `person = Models.ForeignKey(Person)`. My question is what is the equivalent to a ForeignKey in normal Python OOP? Something that'll link each address to it's corresponding Person.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: @GiovanniMacciocu, His question is about how to do it outside `django` not inside `django`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you probably want an list of `addresses` for each `Person`, you could then add the addresses to the `Person` object.

```
class Person(object):
    name = ""
    age  = ""
    addresses = []
```

However, the way you have declared this object will cause all instances of `Person` to share the same `name`, `age`, etc.

You probably meant to write the following, and the equivalent for `class Address`.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.name = ""
       self.age  = ""
       self.addresses = []
```

In order to add the `Address` to the `Person`, you would then write:

```
sally.addresses.append(sally_work)
sally.addresses.append(sally_home)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with the way you are doing things. First and foremost, `name`, `age` etc. should be instance attributes not class attributes. One way to define the classes would be this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Address:
    def __init__(self, title, street, city, state, zip):
        self.title = title
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip
```

You could actually not have fixed interface for storing addresses for people and just use different names for different 'people' like this:

```
sally = Person('Sally', 22)
sally.work_address = Address('Work', ...)
sally.home_address = Address('Home', ...)
```

Another thing to note is that you don't actually need a class to store a bunch of attributes. You can use a `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', ('name', 'age'))
Address = namedtuple('Address', ('title', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I believe you've given me just what I'm looking for! The reason I'm not using a class is because there is some specialized behavior that will be used, so a tuple wouldn't really be convenient for me.